# Magento 2 Separate billing address

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.1

If a customer wants to change their billing address they have to untick the option `My billing and shipping address are the same`, a form then appears for them to fill in.

How can I make this unticked by default with the form already shown?

I believe it has something to do with:

```
Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/billing-address.js
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's purpose of this requirement?

Comment: to make it easy for customers to add their billing address without having to go through an extra step

Comment: Also find this very disturbing. Magento offers the option, to set an address as default shipping or default billing address.

Yet on checkout it always automatically selects the current shipping address as billing address.